# How does Kubernetes handle multiple API versions for the same resource?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver

In Kubernetes we can request resources using different API versions:

```
kubectl get roles.v1.rbac.authorization.k8s.io foo -n bar -oyaml

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: foo
  namespace: bar
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - endpoints
  - secrets
  verbs:
  - create
  - get
  - watch
  - list
  - update
```

```
kubectl get roles.v1beta1.rbac.authorization.k8s.io foo -n bar -oyaml

Warning: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1 Role is deprecated in v1.17+, unavailable in v1.22+; use rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1 Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: foo
  namespace: bar
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - endpoints
  - secrets
  verbs:
  - create
  - get
  - watch
  - list
  - update
```

- Would the API version used to create a resource have an impact on the resource stored in ETCD?
- If a resource was stored when the newer API version (v1) did not exist yet, would this be a problem when the older API version (v1beta1) is removed?
- Would upgrading to Kubernetes v1.22, which removes `rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1`, break already created/stored resources?
- How are resource transformations between different API versions handled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If a resource was stored when the newer API version (v1) did not exist
> yet, would this be a problem when the older API version (v1beta1) is
> removed?

Kubernetes supports a huge elastic deprecation system, which allows you to create, migrate and maintain API versions in time, however(jumping to your next question, you should sometimes manually upgrade  API versions to up-to-date ones)

You can check [Kubernetes Deprecation Policy guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-policy/), that is very important part of keeping cluster in work condition.

Main rules:

- Rule #1: API elements may only be removed by incrementing the version of the API group.
- Rule #2: API objects must be able to round-trip between API versions in a given release without information loss, with the exception of whole REST resources that do not exist in some versions.
- Rule #3: An API version in a given track may not be deprecated until a new API version at least as stable is released.
- Rule #4a: Other than the most recent API versions in each track, older API versions must be supported after their announced deprecation for a certain duration.
- Rule #4b: The "preferred" API version and the "storage version" for a given group may not advance until after a release has been made that supports both the new version and the previous version

You can check also table that describes which API versions are supported in a series of subsequent releases.

---

> Would upgrading to Kubernetes v1.22, which removes
> rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1, break already created/stored
> resources?

I think yes and you have to do some actions according to [1.22 RBAC deprecation resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#rbac-resources-v122)

[image]

---

> How are resource transformations between different API versions
> handled?

Check [What to do](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#what-to-do)

- [Test with deprecated APIs disabled](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#test-with-deprecated-apis-disabled)
- [Locate use of deprecated APIs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#locate-use-of-deprecated-apis)
- [Migrate to non-deprecated APIs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#migrate-to-non-deprecated-apis)

Answer (score 0):

[api_changes](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api_changes.md) should answer the quesionts from Kubernetes developer's view.

> Would the API version used to create a resource have an impact on the resource stored in ETCD?

No. Usually the latest stable version is stored in ETCD. Which version you use to create a resource would be transformed to latest stable version and stored in ETCD

> If a resource was stored when the newer API version (v1) did not exist yet, would this be a problem when the older API version (v1beta1) is removed?

If v1beta1 is no longer supported, all v1beta1 resources should migrate to newer version before the cluster is upgraded.

> Would upgrading to Kubernetes v1.22, which removes rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1, break already created/stored resources?

You need to migrate them before upgrading.

> How are resource transformations between different API versions handled?

Usually there is a internal structure. Any supported API versions could transform from an to the internal structure without loss of information.

What I mean "usually" is that develpers could choose their ways to manage API versions. [api_changes](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api_changes.md) just give us a good practice to help with compatibility and maintainability of managing API version.